# How to iterate and write out Stock symbol and price with a Client Console Application?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

The sample [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr) and documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#callclient) seem to show how to do this with the JavaScript SignalR libray, I am trying on my own to figure this out using a console client application to GetAllStocks without any success.

Here is my client console app code just concentrating on the GetAllStocks not the update at this point :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs;

namespace StockTicker.Client
{
    class Program
    {

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

       private static async Task RunAsync()
        {

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
            IHubProxy stockTickerMini= hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("stockTickerMini");


             stockTickerMini.On("GetAllStocks", stocks =>
                {
                    foreach (var stock in stocks)
                    { Console.WriteLine(stock.Symbol + ":" + stock.Price); }
                });


              await hubConnection.Start();

           }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should probably show the code you wrote so people can help.

Comment: Ok added the client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is incorrect. GetAllStocks is a method that the client can invoke on the server (e.g. it's something the server exposes). You can do:

```
var stocks = await stockTickerMini.Invoke<IEnumerable<Stock>>("GetAllStocks");
```

If you want to get called back when stocks are being updated then you need to look at what the server side is calling back on the clients object:

Which is detailed right here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#establishconnection

Comment: Does the client need a reference to the server?

Comment: The client does not need a server reference to work. Obviously, if you have a type shared between client and server, that can live in a shared assembly. If you choose to have that type live on the server and you want to use that type on the client, then yes, you need a reference.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. If the client needs to use the Stock class then you need a reference to the assembly (project) where Stock is defined on the client.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought but in the example I don't see any mention of referencing the server project assembly where the stock class is defined so that it may be used in the client.